# External Id in salesforce

Tags: soql, query, duplicate-management

I have an external system that needs to update a record in my org. This system only knows the external id, but the problem is that this external id is not unique, e.g. multiple records might have the  external id. Now I am changing the record id to be unique, and I want to query the all records created with a duplicate record id.

How can I perform this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `HAVING` clause for this requirement.

```
SELECT External__c, count(Id) records FROM MyObject__c
GROUP BY External__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

If you are open to using `Apex`, you can generate a `Set<String>` based on the above. If your volume is low enough, you can do it all in one go:

```
Set<String> externalIds = new Set<String>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT External__c FROM MyObject__c
    GROUP BY External__c HAVING count(Id) > 1
]) externalIds.add((String)aggregate.get('External__c'));

List<MyObject__c> duplicates = [
    SELECT Id, External__c FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE External IN :externalIds
];
```

Comment: SELECT External__c, count(Id) records FROM contact
GROUP BY External__c HAVING count(Id) > 1,I tried but I am getting error

Comment: ELECT external__c, count(Id) records FROM
       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Invalid field: 'external__c'

Comment: You have to replace `External__c` with the actual API Name of your field...

Comment: i want to display all the records , i want above query to add Id or name field for displaying @adrian

Comment: @user36188 I don't think you can do it in just one query. What other tools do you have at your disposal? Are you comfortable using `Apex`? `Data Loader`?

Comment: apex class i want

Comment: Um. Why do you want to delete all of them? Are you doing so in production? ***Back up your data***.

Comment: I dont want to delete,i want to know how may records are there with different names thats all

Comment: @user36188 - The code provided will give you a count of All external IDs that are on more than one record. Different names does not appear important as you want to get to a unique external ID and the query will provide that

Comment: @Adrian Larson, i want to display all the recordids,which have same unique field called external in query,i want to know how many records ,please perform query

Comment: @Eric ,@adrian Larson,@tushar sharma i am created the field as set as external Id and now i am chaning the field to set as unique record identifier, i am not able to cahnge,for that i want to query all the duplicate records with different Record id ,How to Query ,The above query displaying count field only,i want all Record ids,which have same external id field

Comment: @Eric ,@Adrian larson see the Link ,http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140715/displaying-duplicate-record-ids/140716#140716 Guide Me for the Answer