# Displaying Duplicate Record Ids for External Id

Tags: externalid

I have created the field set as External Id and now I am changing the field to set as unique record identifier, I am not able to change, because Records exist already with duplicate values for that field.

So I want to query all the duplicate records. How do I perform a query to display the duplicate values for that particular field in test sandbox?

Then I will delete all the fields which contains duplicate External Ids, then I can change the field to Unique. Please anyone Guide me how to write a Query for Displaying the Duplicate Record Ids.

Answer (score 0):

There will most likely be a formula some whizz kid can make up for you but would it not be easier to export into excel and de-dupe on a spreadsheet, amend and re-load into salesforce with data loader?

How many records are we talking?

Comment: How to convert it into Salesforce,guide me what i have to do

Comment: what are the steps I have to follow to change the Unique field for the Particular field Guide Me for the Answer

Comment: So use the dataloader - Export the data with all the fields you require including your custom field. Open in Excel - Use "Find Duplicate" on Excel Data Formatting - Highlight the duplicate values in a colour. Filter the spreadsheet to only show cells using the colour. Change the Unique field ID into whatever you want it to be - then using the Dataloader - load the spreadsheet back into SF using the mapping to update the fields.

Comment: I think this is easier to do like @Paul Rogers says with an extract using a report including the Salesforce Record Id, External Id and whichever other fields you need to identify the records to keep then load the csv to Excel and sort by the external id, highlighting any duplicates. Then for the duplicates copy the Salesforce ID to a separate sheet in Excel, save it as a .csv file and use dataloader to delete those records.

Comment: For Data Loader i want query to extract data,what is the query i have to perform @DaveHumm

Comment: First of all I want query to display the Duplicate Record Ids Please Guide Me

Comment: Why do you need a query to extract the data - a report will do it or data loader you select the relevant fields from the object in d/l. You do not need to pick up just duplicates out of Salesforce instead all the records and use Excel to identify the duplicates.

Comment: I dont want DataLoader, i want to do in test sandbox itself,I want query dUPLIACTE VALUES

Comment: how @DaveHumm please guide me

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question before and get an answer - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/external-id-in-salesforce

Comment: @DaveHumm I am Not getting the Answer for Large Volume of data,that is  why posted here

Comment: @DaveHumm please Come to chat,I will explain My problem clearly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45396/discussion-between-user36188-and-dave-humm).